# How to convert Markdown files into an RSS feed

Tags: python, rss

For our documentation we are using `mkdocs` which is nothing more than a set of `python` scripts which are capable to convert markdown files into an HTML static website.
Now, we need to include in the project a folder structured in this way:

```
+ rss
  - 2017-01-01.md
  - 2017-01-02.md
```

Where each markdown file contains an RSS news.
I found this `markdown` plugin **mdx rss** available in the official Python-Markdown plugins repository:
https://github.com/waylan/Python-Markdown/wiki/Third-Party-Extensions
but I can't get it working.

Is there any tool that convert of a bunch of .md files into an .rss?

Comment: Did you figure it out?